# Is it possible to perform a search on a DBGrid without altering the DataSet or query the base?

Tags: c++, search, sql-server-2008-r2, ado

I am using Embarcadero C++ builder and ADO OLEDB, connected to SQL Server 2008 R2. I fetch the data in a DBGrid, from that DBGrid I want some of the rows that match my search parameters copied on a SGrid.

Is it possible to perform a search on the DBGrid without altering its content or querying the DB?